# Associative Law - Number Sequence

Tags: associativity

I'm stuck in a problem, need Help.

Associative property States that

```
(a + b ) + c = a + (b + c)
```

Which is true

but what if i change the position of the numbers

```
(a + c) + b = a + (c + b)
```

Does it hold true for the associative Law because the answer will still be same..

Stuck in this problem. Need your help with proofs.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's true if it's commutative. You're using the commutative property to commute the c and b.

Comment: Variables are just labels.  In addition $(THING_1 + THING_2) + THING_3 = THING_1 + (THING_2 + THING_3)$ no matter what letter or labels you give them, and no matter what values the have.  (Also you have commutative law too... if you really want to scramble them).

Comment: N. Bar.  It's true if it *ISN'T* commutative.  It's just relabelling *in the same position*.  Let $(a+b) + c=a+(b+c)$.  So let $a'=a; c'=b; b'=c$ and you have $(a'+c') + b' = a' + (c' + b')$.  It's just labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it's true, even when you permute the symbols. Associativity means that
$$(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$$
for any $a, b, c$ in the appropriate set (real numbers perhaps?). It doesn't matter what I substitute in for these variables, this will always be true. Here are some true statements that follow from this:
\begin{align*}
(q + l) + v &= q + (l + v) \\
(1 + 3) + 5 &= 1 + (3 + 5) \\
(a + b) + (x + 1) &= a + (b + (x + 1)) \\
a^x + (b^y + c^z) &= (a^x + b^y) + c^z \\
a + (c + b) &= (a + c) + b \\
a + (a + a) &= (a + a) + a.
\end{align*}
Basically, you can substitute any expression you like in for $a, b, c$, so long as they evaluate to a real number, and you will get a true statement.

Comment: (a + b) + c = a + (b + c ) agreed for this. But what if forthe same numbers i tell my students to go for this grouping as well i.e. (a + b) + c = a + (b + c )  which will be also equal to (a + c) + b

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but in order to conclude that $(a + b) + c = (a + c) + b$, you'll need commutativity $b + c = c + b$ as well.

Comment: but i want clarity on this point that in associative law for three numbers a,b,c we have  (a+b)+c= a+(b+c ) + b but if student writes another option along with these two which is (a+c) +b would it be justified under associative law.

Comment: Well, $(a + b) + c \neq a + (b + c) + b$, unless $b = 0$. No, it is not justified, purely by associative law, to say $(a + c) + b$ is equal to either $(a + b) + c$ or $a + (b + c)$. It is justified with associative and commutative laws together, but not just associative law.